# Recovering the distorted Chinese format and identifying the original Chinese encoding

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, gbk

I am working with a file that has read Chinese Wikipedia content and apparently somehow has been converted to UTF-8 
but not correct.

```
import re,urllib
st=u'1492: Conquest ▒�¢â▒��¬â▒�▒¹of Paradise'
st1= urllib.unquote(st).encode('UTF-8') 
st2= urllib.unquote(st) 
print st
print st1
print st2
```

The output is

```
1492: Conquest ▒�¢â▒��¬â▒�▒¹of Paradise
1492: Conquest â–’ï¿½Â¢Ã¢â–’ï¿½ï¿½Â¬Ã¢â–’ï¿½â–’Â¹of Paradise
1492: Conquest ▒�¢â▒��¬â▒�▒¹of Paradise
```

**EDIT (Extra info found)**
I found out that the original format (whatever that was), went through the following conversion process

```
  line[1]=urllib.quote(line[1])
  try:
      st=urllib.unquote(line[1]).decode("utf-8")
  except UnicodeDecodeError:
      st=urllib.unquote(line[1]).decode("latin1")
```

I don't know the original encoding (probably GBK or GB18030), so I am not sure how to recover the correct text. Is this recoverable?

Comment: The `�` are characters that couldn't be converted to Unicode, so there are now holes in the text - there's no way to retrieve the original byte sequence.

Comment: `print b'1492: Conquest ▒�¢â▒��¬â▒�▒¹of Paradise'.decode('gb18030')` ===
`1492: Conquest 鈻掞拷垄芒鈻掞拷锟铰⑩枓锟解枓鹿of Paradise`. It's Chinese at least, but doesn't look correct. @MarkRansom is probably right about the missing data.

Answer (score 1):

Given the code you show to decode the incoming bytes...

It's likely that trying to decode the bytes from `utf-8` would fail, since there are so many byte combinations that aren't valid in utf-8. Thus your Unicode string probably came from decoding `latin1` instead.

There are also many bytes that aren't valid latin1 characters, but a quick test in Python 2.7 shows that it decodes them anyway. This means that the input bytes were retained, but `print` wasn't able to display them.

```
for x in range(256):
    if chr(x).decode('latin1').encode('latin1') != chr(x):
        print x
```

The following should be able to restore them and decode to the proper code page, if you put the proper code page into the `decode` part:

```
st1 = st.encode('latin1').decode('gb18030')
print st1
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this already but I got the this error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 15-16: ordinal not in range(256)"  I also tried with the decode being "gbk" or "big5"

Comment: @user1848018 that indicates to me that the `utf-8` decode did in fact work, but it generated characters outside of the 0-255 range. Try replacing `'latin1'` with `'utf-8'` in my code above and see if it works. Also, try printing `repr(st)` and adding that information to your question.